# Excel add-in for XML XSD mapping

Tags: c#, xml, excel, dictionary, add-in

I am new to the world of Office Add-Ins  Here is what I am trying to do.

I would like to create an add-in that will:

1. Read column names of an open excel document (xls, xml, csv, etc).
2. Read the fields of a provided XSD XML schema file.
3. Map the fields to columns if they match exactly, otherwise show a message saying that certain columns were not found.

I believe the `Workbook.XmlMaps` property is where I should look, however I wonder if somebody already did something similar or can give me hints/pointers in the right direction.

Comment: Have you read this site [Excel Object Model Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wss56bz7.aspx)?